# Server-side rendering with props

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am developing web-site using reactJS. I want to render one of my pages in server-side with props. Right now i have rendered the page in server-side and loaded the client-side script using the same props which were used to render the page in server-side. check-sum is valid when the page is rendered on my browser. My question is event-handlers are not working in client-side. This is the code I use to pass the same props to client-side rendering

This is the render method of my component

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="elf-profile-page">
        <EducationLevelProgressBar name={firstName} sponsorAmount={this.props.student.sponserAmount} educateLevel={this.props.student.currentGrade} />
        <hr/>
        <StudentDetails firstName={"Udayanga"} lastName={"Perera"} age={12} currentGrade={this.props.student.currentGrade} district={this.props.student.district}location={this.props.student.district + ', ' + this.props.student.province + ' Province'}
        applicationURL={this.props.student.applicationURL} story={this.props.student.description}
        imageGallery={images} letters={this.props.student.letters}/>
        <div className="container-fluid elf-student-profile-more-student-info">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <PersonalProfile
                dateOfBirth={(this.props.student.dateOfBirth.toISOString()).split('T')[0]} joinedDate={(this.props.student.joinedDate.toISOString()).split('T')[0]} gender={this.props.student.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.props.student.gender.slice(1)} liaisonOfficer={"Mr.Sasitha Sonnadara"}
                ambition={this.props.student.ambition} fundsReceived={this.props.fundsReceived} hobbies={this.props.student.hobbies} previousSponsors={this.props.previousSponsors}/>
              <HouseholdInfo father={this.props.student.father} mother={this.props.student.mother} householdIncome={this.props.student.householdIncome} siblings={this.props.student.siblings}/>
              <StudentEducation exams={this.props.student.exams} achievements={this.props.student.achievements} currentSchool={this.props.student.currentSchool} currentGrade={this.props.student.currentGrade} previousSchools={this.props.student.previousSchools}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <NewsFeedTL />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <SocialMediaShare name={firstName} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Credibility />
        <script src="/profile.entry.chunk.js"></script>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The script tag at the end of above code is the client-side bundle generated by webpack.
I use following code to sync props in client-side with the props used in server-side to render my component

```
if ( typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const stringifiedJSON = '"' + document.getElementById('props').innerHTML + '"';
  const container = document.getElementById('app');
  const props = JSON.parse(stringifiedJSON);
  React.render(ProfilePage(props), container);
}
```

last line of above code gives this error

> Cannot call a class as a function

I am using ES6 syntax

Comment: Event handlers are functions. You can't encode functions in JSON.

Comment: I didn't encode functions here. I am encoding my Props here. Actual clien-side code is bundled by webpack and I have added that bundle to my Component

Comment: Well in that case the code snippet isn't all that relevant to the non-working event handlers. Please produce the code where you've defined your event handlers.

Comment: ok let edit my question

Comment: I used the second method under the topic 'Sync props' of this exapmle      http://www.crmarsh.com/react-ssr/

Comment: You mentioned that the event handlers are not working. Where are the event handlers?

Comment: Also, `React.render(ProfilePage(props), container);` should be `React.render(<ProfilePage {...props} />, container);`

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I added your suggestion but still my click events are not working and now I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: _reactDomServer2.default.render is not a function`                                            But my checksum is valid and page is rendering

Comment: when I go to the React Tab using Inspect Elements option it shows this `waiting for roots to load...`